# Layout has no resource identifier?

Tags: android, layout

I have an XML file that has no error, and yet it shows me the wrong message. I don't know why. Alternative methods that help correct the error
This please help me necessary and write the appropriate code 
[see the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQXXE.png)

```
   //layout.xml
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#c0c0c0">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_h"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_Left="@+id/spinner_minutes"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:text="ساعة"
                android:layout_below="@+id/text_timer"
              />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_pam"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_Left="@+id/spinner_minutes"
                android:text="ص/م"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_above="@+id/spinner_minutes3"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/spinner_minutes"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText,RtlSymmetry" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_m"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:layout_Left="@+id/spinner_minutes2"
                android:layout_below="@+id/text_h"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:text="دقيقة"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText,RtlSymmetry" />


            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner_minutes"
                android:layout_width="85dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:entries="@array/fruits"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/spinner_minutes2" />


            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner_minutes2"
                android:layout_width="85dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:entries="@array/fruits"
                android:layout_below="@+id/spinner_minutes"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/text_m"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp" />


            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner_minutes3"
                android:layout_width="85dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:entries="@array/apm"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner_minutes"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/text_m"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/spinner_minutes"
                tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_timer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/button_holder"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/spinner_minutes"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dip">
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_set"
                    android:layout_width="100dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                    android:text="Set"
                    tools:ignore="ButtonStyle,HardcodedText,RtlHardcoded" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_cancel"
                    android:layout_width="100dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
                    android:text="Cancel"
                    tools:ignore="ButtonOrder,ButtonStyle,HardcodedText,RtlHardcoded" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/button_holder2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/text_timer"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
                android:visibility="gone">
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_close"
                    android:layout_width="100dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Close"
                    tools:ignore="ButtonStyle,HardcodedText"/>
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_cancel2"
                    android:layout_width="100dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Cancel"
                    tools:ignore="ButtonOrder,ButtonStyle,HardcodedText" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

//The error message: 
// Error:(8) No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_Left' in package 'android'

Answer (score 1):

There is no `android:layout_Left` property, You might have confused it with `android:layout_toLeftOf`

Answer (score 1):

There is no attribute `layout_Left`
so instead of

```
android:layout_Left="@+id/spinner_minutes"
```

do this:

```
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/spinner_minutes"
```

or

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spinner_minutes"
```

or even better

```
android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/spinner_minutes"
```

or

```
android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/spinner_minutes"
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have `android:layout_Left="@+id/spinner_minutes"` in second TextView.

Comment: Thank you, what's the solution, please?